# How to get a logical expression instead of a value

Tags: symbolic, expression-form

Suppose I want to write out the terms of the binomial distribution:

```
Sum[ Binomial[n, k] q^k (1 - q)^(n - k), {k, 0, n} ]
```

This obviously gives me 1, however I want it to write out each term explicitly. Thus for example if n=2 I want to have:

$q^2 + (1-q)^2 + 2q(1-q)$

How to do this?

Comment: You can do `With[{n = 2}, Sum[Binomial[n, k]*q^k (1 - q)^(n - k), {k, 0, n}]]` where instead of 2 you can put any value you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it depends on the order "n" you are interested in.

If you do for example:

```
Sum[Binomial[#, k]*q^k (1 - q)^(# - k), {k, 0, #}] & @2
```

you get

```
(1 - q)^2 + 2 (1 - q) q + q^2
```

(obviously, you can also define n=2 and run the command you wrote and you would get the same output).
And if you want if for different values of n, you can do for example:

```
Sum[Binomial[#, k]*q^k (1 - q)^(# - k), {k, 0, #}] & /@ Range[10]
```

and you get the case n=1,2,...,10 in a list:

```
{1, (1 - q)^2 + 2 (1 - q) q + q^2, (1 - q)^3 + 3 (1 - q)^2 q + 
  3 (1 - q) q^2 + q^3, (1 - q)^4 + 4 (1 - q)^3 q + 6 (1 - q)^2 q^2 + 
  4 (1 - q) q^3 + q^4, (1 - q)^5 + 5 (1 - q)^4 q + 10 (1 - q)^3 q^2 + 
  10 (1 - q)^2 q^3 + 5 (1 - q) q^4 + q^5, (1 - q)^6 + 6 (1 - q)^5 q + 
  15 (1 - q)^4 q^2 + 20 (1 - q)^3 q^3 + 15 (1 - q)^2 q^4 + 
  6 (1 - q) q^5 + q^6, (1 - q)^7 + 7 (1 - q)^6 q + 21 (1 - q)^5 q^2 + 
  35 (1 - q)^4 q^3 + 35 (1 - q)^3 q^4 + 21 (1 - q)^2 q^5 + 
  7 (1 - q) q^6 + q^7, (1 - q)^8 + 8 (1 - q)^7 q + 28 (1 - q)^6 q^2 + 
  56 (1 - q)^5 q^3 + 70 (1 - q)^4 q^4 + 56 (1 - q)^3 q^5 + 
  28 (1 - q)^2 q^6 + 8 (1 - q) q^7 + q^8, (1 - q)^9 + 9 (1 - q)^8 q + 
  36 (1 - q)^7 q^2 + 84 (1 - q)^6 q^3 + 126 (1 - q)^5 q^4 + 
  126 (1 - q)^4 q^5 + 84 (1 - q)^3 q^6 + 36 (1 - q)^2 q^7 + 
  9 (1 - q) q^8 + q^9, (1 - q)^10 + 10 (1 - q)^9 q + 
  45 (1 - q)^8 q^2 + 120 (1 - q)^7 q^3 + 210 (1 - q)^6 q^4 + 
  252 (1 - q)^5 q^5 + 210 (1 - q)^4 q^6 + 120 (1 - q)^3 q^7 + 
  45 (1 - q)^2 q^8 + 10 (1 - q) q^9 + q^10}
```